# New machine build - Not able to boot from USB

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, bios, usb-installation

Working at getting my son's new machine running but running into a wall.

Trying to boot from flash drive and go straight into Gnu Grub w list of options (Ubuntu/Ubuntu-safe graphics/OEM/Next vol/UEFI Firmware Settings).  Selecting any of the first few and my flash drive flashes (has a light in it) for 10 secs then the machine powers down.  Reboot and sends me back into the Gnu Grub list.

New machine build:

- MSI B460M PRO-VDH WiFi
- i5 10400 w integrated graphics
- one stick of 8gig ram
- old SSD I had - might have had Win7 on it
- Plan to use integrated graphics

USB Flash Drive:

- downloaded Ubuntu 20.04.0.0-desktop-amd64.iso
- Used Rufus to create bootable flash drive
- Options: GPT Partition / UEFI (non CSM) Target system / Fat32
- Am able to boot into Ubuntu on two laptops w this flash drive
- - Puts me into the "Try" or "Install" screen as expected

Bios:

- MSI Fast Boot - disabled
- Fast Boot - disabled
- Secure Boot - tried disabled & enabled
- Flashed from 1.40 to 1.51

Tests:

- I can boot up the machine w a WinPE flash drive (from Macrium for windows machines)  Looks fine
- Tried two different USB flash drive (USB 2.0 and 3.0) and DVD drive.
- All got me the same results - did not go to the "Try or Install" - straight into the Gnu Grub screen.  Selecting different options gave me the same result - reads from flash drive for 10 secs then powered down & back up.

Question:

- What am I missing?

Additional background: This is my 13 yr old kid's first build and he's holding up great and I'd really like to get this running.  Teach him to stick with it.  Took hours before we figured out to reset the CMOS to even get into bios.

Comment: Since you have demonstrated that the USB is properly made and boots properly into a test system, seems like you are describing a hardware fault on the new-build system instead of a problem with Ubuntu. Check the RAM seating and other connections. If your BIOS has the option, check temperatures to ensure they are reasonable (no bad sensors). Double-check that your power-supply is putting out what is promised -- I once had a somewhat similar experience that turned out to be a faulty power supply.

Comment: The "Try or Install" option is a Syslinux thing. 20.04 UEFI boots use GRUB2. I have tried to list every possibility for a Boot drive not booting in this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot. If you have a new reason give it as an answer and I will upvote it.

Comment: Thanks for the input/comments.
Here's a question - the mobo has an 8-pin connector for CPU power but my power supply just has a 4 pin cable.  Do I need an 8-pin connector?  
The mobo seems to indicate that the 4-pin is OK but maybe because I'm using integrated graphics...  Am not overclocking.

Comment: If you have an external enclosure that fits the internal drive, you could install Ubuntu to it from one of the laptops and see if that works.

Answer (score 1):

It was the power supply.  We hooked up a separate PSU to the system and it started right up.
I guess that's a lesson in what happens when you cheap out on the PSU.
Thanks for all of the thoughtful comments - very much appreciated!